# Acoustic Guitar how can be connected to Ubuntu and make it sound like Electrical guitar to make metal sounds?

Tags: sound, music, jack, audacity, tuxguitar

I have a Acoustic Guitar, which has audio output jack is there any way i can connect that jack to Ubuntu microphone in and then use some existing software which will make the Guitar sound like metal sounds?

Something like using my Ubuntu to replace the need of Electrical guitars? Which tools and how it can be done any guides please?

**Follow up:**

[image]

1) Download and install "Rakarrack"
- this helps to make guitar to any effects (metal, or anything almost)

2) Effects sample

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUq49jRBr60
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Jb7BEsHwLc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need a special Auto card. Such things can be found in music stores. You simply need to chose one that is compatible with Ubuntu. If that is the case, the software distributed with the card should allow to do such things. Some devices are USB connected to PC. Of course you can try to use your built-in audo card, but most probably it won't work as expected - there will be about 1 or 2 seconds of latency between what you play and what you hear.

[Examples of such devices.](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UCG102.aspx) However this one doesn't work with Linux. At least it is not mentioned.

Comment: You need to read the manual, because every device is different, has different features. And the most important: Find one that supporsts Lunux Ubuntu, or is known to work with such system. Do not buy the one that is described as working with Win of Mac only.

Comment: which one works with Ubuntu can you add here later maybe? I will also add if i find some. Then we can have a good answer who always use Ubuntu. I am suffering with Ubuntu want other users suffer less on those.

Comment: In general it works in such way: guitar plays what it plays, the signal is changed electronically - on so called distortion boxes (also called effects) or in your computer (dependently where you connected yout guitar to) - therefore your device requires proper software. Do speak with the seller after you decide to something, and dont be hasty (i know it is not easy).

Comment: [see this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXIFi2LPQp0) might be also helpful. However proper music card is required in my opinion. The best way to obtain one working with Linux is to visit some big music store.

Comment: do you see something like that here? http://www.thomann.de/

Comment: Not really, I haven't noticed any working with Linux. Only Win and Mac.

Comment: I am sure that there are such things, however I haven't play my guitar for 6 years now. I'd advice to search some formus for guitar players and ask what devices they use if they have Linux.

Comment: OK - I edited in my question section, the way to make it at-least work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know wich sound cards are linux compatible (and can provide low latency audio) see [that page](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aMain).

But in my opinion it will be hard to have a "metal" sound with an acoustic guitar....

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I use a generic USB Guitar Link purchased online for $8.00 US... Yes you can get some pretty heavy sounds from an acoustic/electric guitar using Rakarrack... Not quite the same as you would with regular pickups but not too bad. Some frequencies can feedback if you are too loud or too close to the amplifier. Latency using the USB card is around 10MS, you might do better than that... Some built in cards can work but others fail miserably ... I'd spend the $8.00 online ...